Passing WebSocket request from Sveltekit to Elysiajs
I have a backend server written with Elysiajs, and I have integrated it with Sveltekit App.
The problem is that the rest routes work as expected but the WS ones don't because Sveltekit do not support WS nativly, how could I intercept the WS request coming to the Sveltekit app and pass them to ElysiaJS?
import { backend } from "backend"; // ElysiaJS instance

type RequestHandler = (v: { request: Request }) => Response | Promise<Response>;

export const GET: RequestHandler = ({ request }) => backend.handle(request);
export const POST: RequestHandler = ({ request }) => backend.handle(request);
export const PATCH: RequestHandler = ({ request }) => backend.handle(request);
export const DELETE: RequestHandler = ({ request }) => backend.handle(request);

/* 
 Sveltekit doesn't support this right now.
 And this is what I want to achieve (Passing WS requests to backend.handle).
*/
export const WS: RequestHandler = ({ request }) => backend.handle(request);

as I mentioned this code can handle rest endpoint but because Sveltekit does not support WS nativly the WS endpoints don't work.
Example requests:
GET http://localhost:5173/api/v1/work/rest => Get handled.
GET ws://localhost:5173/api/v1/work/realtime/workNotification => Keep hanging.
I have tried to write a vite plug in to transform the request, but that didn't work

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
